# Car universal remote function won't learn our garage door opener

Tags: buick, lacrosse, homelink

So, we have a new-to-us vehicle since the last time I posted (a 2015 Buick Lacrosse, these days), but that has resurfaced an old issue: our car's "universal remote control" (what other folks here seem to call HomeLink, but I'm not sure if that trade name applies to our vehicle) isn't able to learn how to work our garage door opener, a Craftsman 139.53966SRT (made by Chamberlain).

We have the OEM keyfob remote, which works fine; however, when we try to use either procedure in the car's manual for programming the car's remote, the light corresponding to the button we're trying to program simply blinks rapidly as soon as we start the process, which is a condition not even mentioned in the car's owner's manual.  How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Do you have an owner's manual for the Buick? If so, does it say anything about seeing this response when trying to program the in-car remote?

Comment: @David -- edited to clarify

Comment: I found the car's manual here: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/922044/Lacrosse-2015-Buick.html?page=164#manual Have you tried programming each of three in-car circuits? Have you called the telephone help line or gone to Homelink.com as described on Page 5-51?

Comment: @David -- have not tried homelink.com yet, will do

Comment: I asked  a young teen do it for me. It took about 2 minutes to sync 2 doors with each of 2 cars.

Comment: @blacksmith37  Absolutely.  The only problem I had was all the whining when I tried to keep the teen in my toolbox for next time . . .

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that your garage door opener using a rolling code style of security. If this is the case once the in car buttons are programmed it will be necessary to press a corresponding button on the garage door opener itself. There should be small learn or program button the unit. Simply press this button on the opener and go back into your car and press the button your programmed earlier several times until the garage door responds.

FYI, this may not be the case but I know I had a similar issue when programming my car's homelink and this was why.

Anyways, best of luck!